# How to get custom headers in Nestjs that is set from angular application? I am getting instance of is not an object ERROR

Tags: node.js, angular, http-post, nestjs, request-headers

I am trying to use the custom headers that is sent from angular, but I could not able to console it in nestJs framework in Node App.

Below are the ways That I am tried to set my headers.

Client Side Code

Try1

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append("mycustomkey", "value");
    headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    headers = headers.set(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "http://localhost:3600"
    );
```

Try2

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    headers.set("mycustomkey", "value");
    headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3600");
```

Try3

```
const headerDict = {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
      Accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3600",
      "mycustomkey", "value",
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict),
    };
```

And It is the Post Call, here I included the headers

```
return this.http
      .post(this.URL, data, {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: "text" as "json",
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          return response;
        })
      );
```

Server side Code which is in nestJs, here also I have tried two methods direct headers and req.headers

Try 1

```
async dycData(@Req() req, @Res() res, @Headers('mycustomkey') mykey:string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('It is inside API');
    if (req) {
      console.log('my key that is setted from the header', mykey);
    const rawData = await rawbody(req);
      const myData = rawData.toString().trim();
      const encryptedString= this.decrypt(myData, mykey)
      res.status(200).send(encryptedString);
    }
})
```

Try 2

```
async dycData(@Req() req, @Res() res, ): Promise<any> {
    console.log('It is inside API');
    if (req) {
      console.log('my key that is setted from the header', req.headers.mycustomkey);
      const rawData = await rawbody(req);
      const myData = rawData.toString().trim();
      const encryptedString= this.decrypt(myData, mycustomkey)
      res.status(200).send(encryptedString);
    }
})
```

But it is showing the below error
`(node:38432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object at ExpressAdapter.reply (C:\Users\service\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:24:18) at ExceptionsHandler.catch (C:\Users\service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\base-exception-filter.js:26:24) at ExceptionsHandler.next (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\exceptions-handler.js:16:20) at C:\Users\Workspace\Workspace\Angular\\service\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:13:35 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\l\service\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) at C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) at next (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\Workspace\Angular\service\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7) (node:38432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag` --unhandled-rejections=strict `(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:38432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

pls help to receive the header data from angular app to node app

Comment: Why do you have `@Res()` in your route handlers? Do you have any logs showing up in the terminal?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  Kindly Please check the above code, req is passed dierectly to rawBody

Comment: Okay. That doesn't really answer my question though. Why are you injecting `@Res()` and do you have any logs in your terminal? A stack trace would be useful here

Comment: Yes I am Having  route handlers like @Post('/decipher'), also kindly please see the error updated above in my question that I got in the terminal I could not even console the req.headers

Comment: This is directly in the exception filter. Is there nothing before this? I would assume the filter is probably receiving a string instead of an object for the exception, but that's the only guess I have at the moment. It's not really clear what's happening